# error: project cannot be converted into string

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv, object

While reading from a CSV file, I am trying to create a new object for each line of the CSV file. I keep getting an error that says:

```
error: incompatible types: project cannot be converted to String
                    Project[i] = projectOne;
```

How can I fix this?

```java
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
    String[] Project = new String[lineSplit.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++)
    {
        //Creating a new project object called projectOne
        project projectOne = new project(
                 lineSplit[0],lineSplit[1],lineSplit[2],
                 lineSplit[3],lineSplit[4],lineSplit[5]);
        Project[i] = projectOne;
    }

    System.out.println(Project[1]);
    
}
```

I checked project.java and it was a String, so I am confused

Comment: The variable `Project` is declared as a `String[]`. You cannot assign a `Project` to a `String` array element.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your file contains one project per line. There is no need for that inner `for` loop.

Please also follow the java naming conventions. Classes such as your `project` class should be uppercase, variable such as your `Project` should be lowercase.

If you want to convert each line to a `Project` and want to collect those, I would advise you to use a `List`:

```
  List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
  while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineSplit = line.split(",");
    Project projectOne = new Project(lineSplit[0],lineSplit[1],lineSplit[2],lineSplit[3],lineSplit[4],lineSplit[5]);
    projects.add(projectOne);
  }
  System.out.println(projects.get(1));
```